# Ensure string start and end can be matched, otherwise fail regex

Tags: .net, regex

I have this regex:

```
{link=([^|{}]+)|([^|{}]+)|([^|{}]+)}
```

this works great and returns me three groups between the pipe symbols, ie. `this`, `that` and `blah` from `{link=this|that|blah}`. As long as the text contains no pipe, or two curly braces (as they are reserved words in my tag builder.)

However I am still getting a match if I am testing the string 'fsdjklrwenklw' or anything for that matter, I think it's because it doesn't care if "`{link=`" matches or not, as any string will then be matched in the very first back reference.

Probably terribly written, could somebody help me out?
I must only get back references for strings that start with "`{link=`" and end with "`}`".

PS. I have tried the simple prefix and suffix of `\A \z`, this does not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` characters.

Your regex is being parsed as `{link=([^|{}]+)` `|` `([^|{}]+)` `|` `([^|{}]+)}`.
The `|` characters mean 'or', so it matches either the first part or the second part o the first part.

You need to write `{link=([^|{}]+)\|([^|{}]+)\|([^|{}]+)}`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that part is working now.  Do you know how I could make each backreference group optional, but having at least one? As in, either {link=test}, {link=test|test} or {link=test|test|test} ?

Comment: I might have a go at adding another pipe and trying that.  I think I intended to use that pipe for OR, but actually wanted to test a pipe string as well.

Comment: Sorry I'm stuck on my second requirement, if you have any ideas please let me know.